# Is it legal in the US to force you to buy insurance (as a bundle) for something you already have insurance for?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, rental-property, insurance, antitrust-law

For example, a company that rents out car parking spaces requires that I will also buy insurance for the property inside my car, while I already have insurance for the property inside my car.

For example, the company may require that the coverage for the property inside my car may only be part of home owner insurance, but not car insurance.

If the coverage for the property inside my car is part of my car insurance, the company does not accept this coverage and forces me to buy another policy that covers again the property in the car, which is already covered by my car insurance.

Comment: Maybe you could switch the insurance policy?

Comment: I'm asking about the legal principle.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the 50 states plus non-states has their own laws, but there is nothing general about contract or other law in the US that forces a rental facility to accept customers who don't have / won't get the insurance that they require. It is a reasonable requirement, because it protects their interest insofar as angry customers might sue the facility because their car was broken into, and many of them would mistakenly believe that their car insurance covers theft or destruction of contents (thus leading to a desire to sue, to cover the property loss). It may be just too much hassle and too risky for them to *assume* the correctness of a customer's claim that they already have adequate coverage and will maintain said coverage, with no practical means to verify the claim.

Comment: It's not answering the question.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what part I left unanswered, also saying what state's laws you are working under.

Comment: You left the whole thing out. You wrote what you think may motivate parking renters to require insurance from a tenant. That was not my question. My question was is it LEGAL to require a tenant to purchase some specific insurance product (as a bundle) when the tenant already has insurance that covers the same thing. And you missed the "For example" part. I was not asking about car parking specifically, it was just an example. I am interested in the laws of GA and SC.